# Processing sets without taking transpose matrix

Tags: r, matrix, optimization, combinatorics, dice

This algorithm generates all possible roll sums with a set of dice, and the probability of their occurrence. However, the additions I made to accommodate dropping min and max values slowed it down considerably. The specific issue I would like to address is, is there a way to process my number sets without having to take the transpose matrix of all my possible rolls? I cannot figure out how to handle data in the other orientation. This gets very clunky when you get to even n^6 possibilities. Any additional advice is welcome.

```
diceroller <- function(dicenumber, dicesize, mindrop, maxdrop)
{
  parallel_rolls <- matrix(1:dicesize, dicesize, dicenumber)
  tmat <- t(parallel_rolls)
  all_possible_rolls <-
    do.call(expand.grid, split(tmat, rep(1:nrow(tmat),     ncol(tmat))))
  if (mindrop > 0)
  {
    for (j in 1:mindrop)
    {
      for (i in 1:(dicesize ^ dicenumber))
      {
        all_possible_rolls[i, which.min(all_possible_rolls[i, ])] <- NA
      }
    }
  }
  if (maxdrop > 0)
  {
    for (l in 1:maxdrop)
    {
      for (i in 1:(dicesize ^ dicenumber))
      {
        all_possible_rolls[i, which.max(all_possible_rolls[i, ])] <- NA
      }
    }
  }
  rollsum     <- apply(all_possible_rolls, 1, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
  truedicenum <- (dicenumber - (mindrop + maxdrop))
  hist(rollsum, breaks = c((truedicenum - 1):(truedicenum * dicesize)))

  rollfreq    <- as.data.frame(table(rollsum))
  rollfreqpct <- c((rollfreq[2] / (dicesize ^ dicenumber)) * 100)
  fulltable   <- cbind(rollfreq, rollfreqpct)

  print(fulltable)
  print(paste("total possible roll sets:", sum(rollfreq[2]), sep = " "))
  print(paste("mean roll:", mean(rollsum), sep = " "))
  print(paste("roll sd:", sd(rollsum), sep = " "))
}
```

Example:

```
diceroller(1, 8, 0, 0)
```

Benchmarks:

```
rbenchmark::benchmark(diceroller(3, 6, 1, 2))
```

> ```
>                     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
> 1 diceroller(3, 6, 1, 2)          100    7.33        1      7.12     0.08         NA        NA
> ```

Comment: Could you post an example of a function run?

Comment: Might be good to post your benchmarking code too and have a standard example run for us to compare against that benchmark. Also, explaining what drops are about would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses. I'm sort of new to all this, so would you mind explaining how I could post a function run? Also I have the code for the version that doesn't do drops if you would like me to post that too. As far as what drops mean. Imagine you roll 4 dice and you only keep the 3 highest ones. In that case, you would have "dropped" the lowest one. So dropmin means you get rid of the lowest n values in any given set of rolls.

Comment: @Krivand Thank you for the explanation, now I understand. No need to post mode code. I am going to edit your question right now to add an example function run. Please feel free to edit my edit.

Comment: Do you mean you want to avoid t in the 2nd line of body?

Comment: Where is `all_possible_rolls` even transposed?

Comment: @erocoar First the algorithm generates a set of numbers for each die, so if you had a three six-sided dice, it would create three columns whose rows would contain the values 1-6. It then creates the transpose matrix of that and processes the transpose version of the matrix.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Yes, I would really like to get rid of that transpose and expand grid on my rolls directly, however, I could not figure out how to do this without first transposing it.

Comment: Use `matrix(..., byrow = TRUE)`

Comment: Why are there 2 outer `for` loops with `j` and `l` as the iterated variables but which never use them and thus don't seem to change anything?

Comment: @Hack-R Thanks for noticing! I added them in an earlier iteration of the code because it wasn't running without them. I made the removals and it runs fine without them now.

Comment: @Hack-R I remember why I added them now. In any test case where you do not have drops, the algorithm fails without them and gives you the following error. Error in hist.default(rollsum, breaks = c((truedicenum - 1):(truedicenum *  : 
  some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'

Comment: Won't it throw them regardless? With 3 dices, setting 3 to NA and then drawing a histogram ... cannot work

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks! I will try implementing this.

Comment: @erocoar Though I am not totally sure why it doesn't work without the outer loop, I do have one theory. If you do not have the outer loop and your case is zero, it will try to repeat j or l in 1:0.

Comment: Yeah, and if you have drops, it will only consider a single one without them

Comment: Change `apply(all_possible_rolls, 1, sum, na.rm = TRUE)` to `rowSums(all_possible_rolls,  na.rm = TRUE)`. Also, both double loops have inner operations that only involve "i" index, but not either "j" or "l", the two outer indices.

Answer (score 0):

Using `lapply` to construct `parallel_roles` as a list directly and replacing some of the for loops with apply improves the speed a bit

```
diceroller <- function(dicenumber, dicesize, mindrop, maxdrop) 
{
  all_possible_rolls <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(1:dicenumber, function(x) 1:dicesize))

  if (mindrop > 0) {
    all_possible_rolls <- t(apply(all_possible_rolls, 1, function(x) {
      for (i in 1:mindrop) {
        x[which.min(x)] <- NA
      }
      x
    }))
  }

  if (maxdrop > 0) {
    all_possible_rolls <- t(apply(all_possible_rolls, 1, function(x) {
      for (i in 1:maxdrop) {
        x[which.max(x)] <- NA
      }
      x
    }))
  }

  rollsum <- rowSums(all_possible_rolls, na.rm = TRUE)
  truedicenum <- dicenumber - (mindrop + maxdrop)
  rollfreq <- as.data.frame(table(rollsum))
  rollfreqpct <- c((rollfreq[2]/(dicesize^dicenumber))*100)
  fulltable <- cbind(rollfreq, rollfreqpct)
  hist(rollsum, breaks = c((truedicenum - 1):(truedicenum * dicesize)))
  return()
}

rbenchmark::benchmark(diceroller_old(3, 6, 1, 1))
                     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 diceroller_old(3, 6, 1, 1)          100    4.64        1      3.95     0.37         NA        NA

rbenchmark::benchmark(diceroller(3, 6, 1, 1))
                    test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 diceroller(3, 6, 1, 1)          100    1.86        1      1.19     0.44         NA        NA
```